# Overlaying plots with log and lin axes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to graph two datasets on the same plot. The sets have the same x values. One set should be plotted on a log scale in y, the other should be plotted on a lin scale in y. For this post a fake dataset is created as

```
library(pracma)
x<-logseq(0.1,100,60)
y1<-logseq(50,2000,60)
y2<-linspace(0,90,60)
d<-data.frame(x,y1,y2)
```

I am basically trying to recreate this plot from excel. The log space points are shown in red, lin space in blue.

The closest I have been able to get in R so far is using

```
scaleFactor<-max(d[,2])/max(d[,3])

Bode<-ggplot(data=d, aes(x=d[,1]))+
geom_point(aes(y=d[,2]), col="red")+
geom_point(aes(y=d[,3]*scaleFactor))+
scale_y_continuous(name="|Z|, ohm",
                   sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="Phase, deg."))+
scale_x_log10()+
theme_bw()+
ggtitle(plotTitle)+
labs(x="Frequency, Hz")+
theme(
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  axis.title.y.left=element_text(color="red"),
  axis.text.y.left =element_text(color="red")
  )
```

Which outputs the below graph showing the red data and black data in the same graph but the red data is on a lin scale.

It is close, but I really need the red data to be on a log scale. Is this functionality even available on ggplot2? Other graphing libraries wold also be helpful.

Edited to be more reproducible.

Comment: Missing the chart.

Comment: @cobraface. Rememberto add the picture as well.

Comment: Sorry I can't add pictures because I don't have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

If `base::plot` works for you this can be done with `par(new=T)`

```
set.seed(1234)
data1 <- runif(10)
data2 <- runif(10)


par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,4.1))
plot(data1,col="red",pch=19,xlab="Index",ylab="Axis 1")
par(new=T)
plot(data2,col="blue",log="y",pch=19,axes=F,xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4)
mtext(text= "Axis 2",side = 4,line=2)
```

[image]

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work, it only seems to want to graph the index values in x rather than the values of the datafram I'm working with.

Comment: You have to supply  values for x and y if you want to do this. Since you did not provide a reproducible example I could only show this with a generic example

Comment: I have edited the post to include a false data set and for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a usable solution by taking the log of one of the datasets and replotting it on a linear axis. This way both y axes are linear which ggplot likes but the data shows log-linear behavior.

```
library(pracma)

x<-logseq(0.1,100,60)

y1<-logseq(50,2000,60)
y1<-log10(y1)

y2<-linspace(0,90,60)
d<-data.frame(x,y1,y2)

scaleFactor<-max(d[,2])/max(d[,3])


library(ggplot2)
Bode<-ggplot(data=d, aes(x=d[,1]))+
geom_point(aes(y=d[,2]), col="red")+
geom_point(aes(y=d[,3]*scaleFactor))+
scale_y_continuous(name="|Z|, ohm",
                   sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name="Phase, deg."))+
scale_x_log10()+
theme_bw()+
labs(x="Frequency, Hz")+
theme(
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  axis.title.y.left=element_text(color="red"),
  axis.text.y.left =element_text(color="red")
  )
```